# Intel xdk vs visual studio +Cordova

Tags: html, hybrid-mobile-app

I wanted to Start  to learn APP delevoping with HTML, but there i have 2 choices

1. Cordova with VS Studio 2015
2. Cordova with Intel xdk

In my opinion cordova with vs Studio 2015 has the best folder structure and Environment but i dont know .

What would you suggest me?

Comment: I use Intel XDK and I saw that it's quite good except the performance when running is not high, sometimes it become lag. But it's so useful for testing and building application. I suggest choosing VS Studio, this still the best choice ^^

Answer (score 0):

I say try both and stick with what you like I for my self think that It depends in the project your doing since not all cordova plugins work in intel xdk you should try and see if the plugins you want to use on your project are compatible with intel XDK